# How can I save the changes in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008, I have created the database and the table with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Every time I make any changes in the columns or in the inserted records it shows an alert message says "saving changes is not permitted......."

I seriously need your help <3

thank you

Comment: How are you trying to change anything? Sql Server Management Studio? Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default SQL Server Management Studio prevents you from running scripts that will require you to drop and re-create the table, which includes modifications to the columns. You can turn that dialog off in the options:

> Tools -> Options -> Designers

Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation." Hit Ok.

And then try again.

Comment: I answered this before it was pointed out this was a duplicate. If it's closed a duplicate, will this answer be deleted automatically? If not, could someone do that? Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it won't affect you.  Better leave it as answer.  Moderators will take care :)